# I have a memory leak and can't find it

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-fragments, memory-leaks

This is my code. I am programing an app and using firebase to load a random users photo, but after i realod a couple of times this fragment, it crashes due to memory leak. I have been looking for it for ages. please help :)

how my app works:

- Create a user
- user takes a photo
- random other users (or the same users) photo appers
- the user rates a picture and then a new one comes up

public class RatingFragment extends Fragment {

```
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ImageView imageView;
private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
private DataSnapshot childSnapshot;
private User user, newUser;
private RatingBar ratingBar;
private Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

public RatingFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view;
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rating, container, false);

    tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tabLayoutRating);
    tabLayout.setTabTextColors(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.WHITE));
    tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.WHITE);

    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("users");

    imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.ivRandomPhoto);

    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            int userCount = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
            int rand = random.nextInt(userCount);
            Iterator itr = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();

            for (int i = 0; i < rand; i++) {
                itr.next();
            }
            childSnapshot = (DataSnapshot) itr.next();
            user = childSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(user.getNewPhoto()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    ratingBar = view.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);

    ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float v, boolean b) {
            newUser = new User (user.getUserId(),user.getUsername(),user.getPhotos(),user.getAverageRating(),user.getPoints()+1,user.getNewPhoto());
            databaseReference.child(user.getUserId()).setValue(newUser);
            ratingBar.setRating(0);
        }
    });

    TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(1);
    tab.select();

    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            switch (tab.getPosition()) {
                case 0:
                    CropFragment cropFragment = new CropFragment();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_framelayout, cropFragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

    return view;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding ValueEventListener in onCreateView but, as far as I can see, you're not removing it anytime. Apart from this, I'm not able to see any other source of memory leak.

Comment: Thank you soooo much! :)

Comment: I'm glad it solved your problem. Please consider to upvote and accept my answer